# eclipse maya cmds auto completion

Tags: python, eclipse, autocomplete, maya

Recently i have installed eclipse ide and the problem is i get auto complete popup menu for maya cmds, maya api and pymel but

1. After typing "maya.cmds." no commands can be seen
2. After typing "maya." i dont get api classes but cmds can be seen
3. I dont get "pymel" at all in popup menu

but i dont have any problem with pyqt. After seeing this tutorial

http://www.creativecrash.com/maya/t...e-as-a-maya-ide

i got auto competion for pymel and maya api but not for cmds.

another info i dont have any problem in maya script editor

hope this is clear thank you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Maya version >= 2011, Maya ships with files required for autocompletion in a folder called devkit.

Here is a small tutorial as to how to use this: http://www.creativecrash.com/maya/tutorials/development-api/c/eclipse-auto-completion-for-maya-commands

This way is simple, straightforward and works with other great IDEs too like PyCharm.

#### Update:

In Eclipse:

1. Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreter - Python
2. Select MayaPy
3. Open the "Predefined" tab
4. Click on "New..."
5. Navigate to and add the pypredef folder in your extras/completion/ folder in your Maya devkit directory.
   [image]
6. Click on Ok.
7. Make sure your project is using the MayaPy interpreter.

Auto-completion will now start working.
[image]

If you want to do more, check this [tutorial](http://techartninja.com/using-eclipse-with-maya-a-quick-reference/) out. It has some very specific straightforward steps for setting up auto-complete for Maya in Eclipse.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i did not get any results and yes am using maya 2011

Comment: I have updated my answer with more detailed steps. Try them and see.

Comment: after checking this tutorial and following step by step my problem has been solved thanks alot karthik :)